# Как понять какое допустимое количество пользователей может потянуть сайт?

Tags: php, apache, google-chrome, тестирование

В общем пишу сайт, добрался до оптимизации. В инструментах разработчика нашел способ определять за какое время прогружается сайт. Вот скрины того что я нашел:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда я запускаю этот инструмент то загрузка отображается только для моего запроса - как мне понять какое допустимое количество пользователей может потянуть мой сайт?

И если не сложно глядя на эти фото - скажите нормальные ли указанные тут значения(в плане не долго ли это для сайта), что можно улучшить?

Сайт работает на Apache,

backend на PHP,

скорость интернета upload 500 kbit/s,

download 1000 kbit/s

Железо i5-10500h,

rtx3050,

работает на Ubuntu 22.04

графика вся отрисовывается на видеокарте в производительном режиме

Не знаю нужно ли это но на всякий случай написал

Comment: посмотри locust (питоновская библа) или Яндекс.Танк

Comment: "Не знаю нужно ли это". Нет, не нужно. Никакую ррафику веб сайт вообще не отрисовывает. Видеокарту можно (и нужно) выкинуть.

Comment: upload 500 kbit/s и download 1000 kbit/s. Страшно задавать вопрос, но ты это написал максимальную пропускную способность?

Comment: @SemyonBayandin , да, как бы это странно не звучало но для того места где я живу это еще неплохая скорость)

Comment: @ReijiAkkerman тебе правильно про видеокарту сказали. В сервере она не нужна от слова совсем. А вот насчёт пропускной способности: я зайду на твой сайт, начну тыкать на F5 без остановки и у тебя сайт тупо ляжет. Такая скорость совершенно недопустима для того, чтобы сайт хостить

Comment: @SemyonBayandin, а разве эта симуляция ограничения пропускной способности в инструментах разработчика в хроме не про клиента? Как она относится к серверу?

Comment: @ReijiAkkerman Теперь ты меня запутал. 1000 Kbit/s (download) и 500 Kbit/s (upload) - так это симуляция ограничения скорости или это реальная пропускная способность твоей сети?

Comment: @SemyonBayandin в местах где я нахожусь - примерно такая скорость максимальная, и так как пока мой сайт находится на стадии разработки и кроме как на `localhost` нигде не размещен я решил узнать как он будет грузиться у человека не проживающего как и я в городе. Так как на `localhost` сайт в браузере открывается моментально я поставил ограничение более менее напоминающее реальные условия российских деревень. Понятное дело размещать сайт у себя при такой скорости я не буду. Лучше уж тогда арендовать хостинг для такого дела - и проще и дешевле и быстрее)